# Splunk JAVA SDK - Fetch FiredAlerts (i.e Alerts already triggered)

Tags: java, sdk, splunk

I am trying to fetch the fired alerts using the splunk java sdk. But i am not able to get any reference. Here is the code snippet i have and it is not fetching me any results.

```
FiredAlertGroupCollection firedAlertGroups = service.getFiredAlertGroups();
         System.out.println("Fired Alert : " + firedAlertGroups.size());
         for (FiredAlertGroup entity : firedAlertGroups.values()) {
             EntityCollection<FiredAlert> alerts = entity.getAlerts();
             for (FiredAlert alert : alerts.values()) {
                 System.out.println("alerts >>>> " +alert.getName() +": " + alert.getSavedSearchName()+": " + alert.getTitle());
             }
         }
```

Is there a way, i can filter the alerts fired in the last 24 hours etc.

Please help me on the same.